# missing icons in toolbar

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-access-2003

When I start up my database all toolbar icons display properly but after a short time some of my custom icons disappear - usually the same icons but not always. The icons still work when clicked on the empty space. All my custom icons are 16X16. This happens on only one of my 3 laptops, all running Win 7 SP1. Any ideas on the problem or a workaround? Here is a screen image:

[image]

I am using Access 2003 on this database because it has about 82,000 lines of code and I don't want to go through all the code updating it to work on Access 2013 which I use for other databases.

Comment: 2003 has many bugs.  What have you tried so far?  For example, I'm assuming when you close and re-start it, the icons come back.  Have you tried boning down your host system, closing any and everything possible that is not needed to run, and see if that makes any difference?  Also with that many lines of code, I'm guessing there might be a bug in your code, even when it runs correctly on other boxes.  And failing any solution, you already have your workaround:  Put a post-it-note at the top of the screen to remind you what icons are there (even if they don't show, you can still click on them).